# Why wont my VerticalViewPager work at the same time as my HorizontalViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

[image]

So basically I'm trying to make this app have all those pages and you can swipe to change the direction whichever pages you want it to. What I don't understand is that they don't work together it's either one or the other or when I connect them together the app needs to be slided weirdly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //HorizontalViewPagerAdapter
        View background = findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
        HorizontalViewPagerAdapter adapter = new HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}
```

This is my `HorizontalViewPager`:

```
public class HorizontalViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public HorizontalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return ChatFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return ControllerFragment.create();
            case 2:
                return StoryFragment.create();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My `ControllerFragment` that is suppose to make it swipe up and down.

```
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ControllerFragment create() {
        return new ControllerFragment();
    }

    VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager;
    VerticalViewPagerAdapter verticalPageAdapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical, null);
        verticalViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.am_scrollView);
        verticalPageAdapter = new VerticalViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        verticalViewPager.setAdapter(verticalPageAdapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical, null);
    }
}


public class VerticalViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public VerticalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return SettingsFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return EmptyFragment.create();
            case 2:
                return ExtrasFragment.create();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

My Empty Fragment

```
public class EmptyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static EmptyFragment create(){
        return new EmptyFragment();
    }
}
```

My MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="c.kristofer.jax2.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/am_background_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/am_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And last of all a fragment for my vertical scroll

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="c.kristofer.jax2.MainActivity">

    <me.kaelaela.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/am_scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: see this library https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager